# printf/sprintf with array arguments instead of variables

Tags: php, arrays, string, printf

Like

```
$args = (
 'var1' => 'abc',
 'var2' => 'def',
);


$text = sprintf('first var is: %1$s, second one is: %2$s', $args);
```

Basically the `$args` variable is dynamic, I don't know if it will have any entries or how many.

The text too, I don't know if it will require variables to be replaced in it, or how many.

How can I make a function like this, that somehow extracts the elements and replaces them in the text if stuff like `%s` `%d`, `%1$s` etc is present?

Comment: If the number of wildcards in the format specifier differs from the number of elements in the array, then what happens?

Comment: Throw a php warning or something :) (this shouldn't happen under normal circumstances)

Comment: if you're referring to the case where there are no wildcards, but there are variables available, then no replacements should be made. But if there are more wild cards then variables, then this would be a error case

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You probably want [`vsprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php).